# tensor flow lite multiple camera compatibility

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I would like to know if tensor flow lite on the raspberry pi 4 
i could'nt find any information on the tensor flow website
is compatible with multiples cameras for finding my cat in my house with multiple cameras

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is not in TensorFlow but in the interfacing the cameras. You can run inference with a batch size of 2, or 4, or however many cameras you have in your house to always keep an eye on your kitty